# Return object to pool when no references point to it

Tags: c#, .net, weak-references

Ok, I want to do the following to me it seems like a good idea so if there's no way to do what I'm asking, I'm sure there's a reasonable alternative.

Anyways, I have a sparse matrix. It's pretty big and mostly empty. I have a class called MatrixNode that's basically a wrapper around each of the cells in the matrix. Through it you can get and set the value of that cell. It also has Up, Down, Left and Right properties that return a new MatrixNode that points to the corresponding cell.

Now, since the matrix is mostly empty, having a live node for each cell, including the empty ones, is an unacceptable memory overhead. The other solution is to make new instances of MatrixNode every time a node is requested. This will make sure that only the needed nodes are kept in the memory and the rest will be collected. What I don't like about it is that a new object has to be created every time. I'm scared about it being too slow.

So here's what I've come up with. Have a dictionary of weak references to nodes. When a node is requested, if it doesn't exist, the dictionary creates it and stores it as a weak reference. If the node does already exist (probably referenced somewhere), it just returns it.
Then, if the node doesn't have any live references left, instead of it being collected, I want to store it in a pool. Later, when a new node is needed, I want to first check if the pool is empty and only make a new node if there isn't one already available that can just have it's data swapped out.

Can this be done?
A better question would be, does .NET already do this for me? Am I right in worrying about the performance of creating single use objects in large numbers?

Comment: If creating new objects gets your panties in a bunch, c# is probably the wrong language for you:P Are you actually have a performance issue? prototype it and see if it works.

Comment: What version of .NET are you using, if you are using newer than .NET 4 then [MemoryCache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) may be of use to you. It fills that "dictionary" roll and the "check for existing in the pool" roll for you.

Comment: If you want to be in so control of memory and bypass GC you can implement part of you code in c++/c using [fixed statment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f58wzh21%28VS.100%29.aspx)

Comment: @Gusdor A possible solution would be to require the user to manually dispatch of the unused nodes. Then I wouldn't have any issues. That's the non-C# way, right? I'm guessing I wouldn't notice many performance issues to be honest, but take this as more of an academic question. Is a thing like this possible to do?

Comment: Why are you guessing about performance issues?   Create a large number of objects and put a stopwatch on it.

Comment: Can you implement yourself RLE encoding (or any other compression method) in your project ?  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of guessing, you should make a performance test to see if there are any issues at all.  You may be surprised to know that managed memory allocation can often outperform explicit allocation because your code doesn't have to pay for deallocation when your data goes out of scope.

Performance may become an issue only when you are allocating new objects so frequently that the garbage collector has no chance to collect them.

That said, there are sparse array implementations in C# already, like [Math.NET](https://github.com/mathnet/mathnet-numerics) and [MetaNumerics](http://metanumerics.codeplex.com/). These libraries are already optimized for performance and will probably avoid performance issues you will run into if you start your implementation from stratch

An [SO search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c#+sparse-matrix) for c# and sparse-matrix will return many related questions, including answers pointing to commercial libraries like [ILNumerics](http://ilnumerics.net/index.html) (has a community edition), [NMath](http://www.centerspace.net/products/nmath) and [Extreme Optimization](http://www.extremeoptimization.com/)'s libraries

Answer (score 1):

Most sparse matrix implementations use one of a few well-known schemes for their data; I generally recommend [CSR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix#Compressed_sparse_row_.28CSR_or_CRS.29) or [CSC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix#Compressed_sparse_column_.28CSC_or_CCS.29), as those are efficient for common operations.

If that seems too complex, you can start using [COO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix#Coordinate_list_.28COO.29). What this means in your code is that you will not store anything for empty members; however, you have an item for every non-empty one. A simple implementation might be:

```
public struct SparseMatrixItem
{
    int Row;
    int Col;
    double Value;
}
```

And your matrix would generally be a simple container:

```
public interface SparseMatrix
{
    public IList<SparseMatrixItem> Items { get; }
}
```

You should make sure that the Items list stays sorted according to the row and col indices, because then you can use binary search to quickly find out if an item exists for a specific (i,j).

Answer (score 1):

The idea of having a pool of objects that people use and then return to the pool is used for *really* expensive objects.  Objects representing a network connection, a new thread, etc.  It sounds like your object is very small and easy to create.  Given that, you're almost certainly going to harm performance pooling it; the overhead of managing the pool will be greater than the cost of just creating a new one each time.

Having lots of short lived very small objects is the exact case that the GC is *designed* to handle quickly.  Creating a new object is dirt cheap; it's just moving a pointer up and clearing out the bits for that object.  The real overhead for objects comes in when a new garbage collection happens; for that it needs to find all "alive" objects and move them around, leaving all "dead" objects in their place.  If your small object doesn't live through a single collection it has added almost no overhead.  Keeping the objects around for a long time (like, say, by pooling them so you can reuse them) means copying them through several collections, consuming a fair bit of resources.